# MANIFEST.MF (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: eclipse, manifest.mf

I am trying to create the project as set out in the tutorial "http://crunchify.com/how-to-build-restful-service-with-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/". I have followed all the steps but I get thee POM error ....

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
C:\Users\xxxxxx\workspace\CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF (The system cannot find the path specified)  pom.xml /CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample line 1  Maven Configuration Problem

I've noticed that I have 2 Web Content folders: One under Deployed Resources, which does contain my MANIFEST.MF file and another at the same level as the Deployed Resources folder. Eclipse seems to be looking for it in the second WebContent folder where it is not located. Is there a simple fix for this?

Comment: The "web" directory is specified in a `wb-resource node` into the `.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component` file. About the first error, when do you get it? When running Maven?

Comment: Hi. When I open Eclipse there are no errors showing against the project in the Problems, however the POM does show red lines under the maven artifact and the asm and json dependencies. But, yes its when I right click on Project and select Run As > Maven Build and enter "clean install" that the error appears against the POM.

Comment: I've had a look at my Eclipse settings folder "...\eclipse\jee-neon\eclipse\configuration\.settings" but it does not contain that file you mention, only "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.prefs" and "org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs".

Comment: No, no. I meant the `.settings` folder **within** the project folder. On another hand, post the error messsage you get in the red lines and the one you get when run "clean install".

Comment: There is something seriously wrong with my project configuration. There are 3 POM files under different folder paths. One under "/.../WebContent/META-INF/maven/CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample/CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample/pom", another under "/.../target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/maven/CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample/CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample/pom.xml" and a third under "/..../target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/maven/CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample/CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample/pom.xml".

Comment: This project was sent to me by a colleague as a zip file. which I imported into Eclipse,  if that gives any clues as to what the issue is. I don't know if this is to do with the  Eclipse version I am using.  I was wondering whether to uninstall this version and try with a different one.  The error msg is posted above. It doesn't show errors when I hover over the POM files.  Also I can't see a "Settings" folder under my project.

Comment: I recommend you to start a new Eclipse project from the scratch: Let it be Maven, let it be Dynamic Web Project, or whatever is needed... And then, copy the source files from the "wrong" project into it. Copy also from the "wrong" pom the dependencies and plugins, step by step, until it fails.

Comment: Hi Santi. I did actually try that first and had other errors. I will give it another go.

Answer (score 67):

I had similar problem and updating the Maven project solved it.

In Eclipse, right click on the project > Maven > Update Project

See this post: 
http://kodurishiva.blogspot.pt/2016/04/manifestmf-system-cannot-find-path.html

This situation returns when I do a `maven clean`.

Answer (score 18):

Thre are two ways to solve this error.

From Eclipse:

**Right-click on the project -> Go to Maven -> Update project.**

[image]

The second way is from maven clean install using the command line maven.

Use the following command:

```
mvn clean
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Libraries tab in the projects' Build Path. JRE system library must be projects's default JRE.

Answer (score 1):

Thre are two ways to solve this error.

From Eclipse:

```
Right-click on the project -> Go to Maven -> Update project.
```

Comment: What is the other way ? you said two ways

Answer (score 1):

Updating Maven project just resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse:

- Check if your project does not have the folder - `src/main/java`.
- Then right-click on the `project -> Click Build Path -> Configure build path` -> click on the `sources` tab in the opened window.
- You will not see the error for the `src/main/java` folder missing.
- Select it and remove it. The error will be gone.